# How to check if two binary trees share a node

Tags: binary-tree, graph-theory, computer-science-theory

Given an array of binary trees find whether any two trees share a node, not value wise, but "pointer" wise. At the bottom I provided an example.

My approach was to iterate through all the trees and store all the leaves (pointers) from each tree into a list, then check if list has any duplicates, but that's a rather slow approach. Is there perhaps a quicker way to solve this?

[image]

Comment: Store the pointers of one tree in a Hash Set. Then traverse the second tree and check membership in the set.

Comment: @trincot Indeed, hash table would be faster. But Is there a better 'overall' approach?

Comment: What do you mean with "overall"? You'll certainly have to visit all nodes of both trees, so the best time complexity is O(n+m). And that is what you get with the hash set.

Comment: Are we allowed to temporarily or permanently modify the trees? Then maybe we can do it in O(#nodes) time and O(1) space.

Comment: @Kelly Let's assume we can, how would you make it in linear time and constant space then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the worst case you will have to traverse all nodes (all pointers) to find a shared node (pointer), as it might happen to be the last one visited. So the best time complexity we can expect to have is O(+) where  and  represent the number of nodes in either tree.

We can achieve this time complexity if we store the pointers from the first tree in a hash set and then traverse the pointers of the second tree to see if any of those is in the set. Assuming that get/set operations on a hash set have an amortized constant time complexity, the overal time complexity will be O(+).

If the same program is responsible for *constructing* the trees, then a reuse of the same node can be detected upon insertion. For instance, reuse of the same node in multiple trees can be completely *avoided* by having the `insert` method of your tree only take a *value* as argument, never a node instance. The method will then encapsulate the actual creation of the node, guaranteeing its uniqueness.

Comment: Thanks! Seems that hashing is the way to go

Answer (score 0):

An idea for O(#nodes) time and O(1) space. It does more traversal work than simple traversals using a hash table, but it doesn't have the cost of using a hash table. I don't know what's better. Might depend on the language.

#### For two trees

Create one extra node. Do a Morris traversal of the first tree. It only modifies right child pointers, so we can use left child pointers for marking nodes as seen. For every tree node without left child, set our extra node as left child. Whenever checking a left child pointer, treat our extra node like a null pointer, i.e., don't visit it. After the traversal, the tree structure is restored, and all originally left-child-less tree nodes now point to our extra node as left child. That includes all leaf nodes.

Do a Morris traversal of the second tree. Again treat pointers to our extra node like null pointers. If we ever do encounter our extra node, we know the trees share a node. If not, then we know the trees don't share a node, since if they did share any, they'd also share a leaf node (just go down from any shared node to a leaf node, that's also shared), and all leafs nodes of the first tree are marked. After the traversal, the second tree is restored.

Do a Morris traversal of the first tree again, this time removing our extra node, restoring the original null pointers.

#### For an array of more than two trees

Mark the first tree as above. Check the second tree as above. Mark the second tree. Check the third. Mark the third. Check the fourth. Mark the fourth. Etc. When you found a shared node or there are no more trees, unmark the marked trees.

Answer (score -2):

Every shared node must have two parents, or an ancestor with two parents.

```
LOOP over nodes
   IF node has two parents
      MARK node as shared
      Mark all descendants as shared.
```

Comment: Well it can be even simpler: `loop over nodes: IF node is shared -> MARK node as shared`

Comment: @Stanley your 'simpler' solution loses the optimization of marking descendants as shared ( thus they can be skipped in the node loop )